# How do I load spring-data(-neo4j)-repositories lazily?

Tags: cdi, spring-data-neo4j

I am using [spring-data-neo4j](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-neo4j/%20spring-data-neo4j) (standalone) in my JavaEE7-application as nice neo4j-OGM.

For time being, I am trying to integrate spring-data-neo4j [repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#tutorial_repository%20repositories) via @Autowired into my project.

```
public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<User> {}
```

I have started writing some JUnit-tests, which are testing beans which themselves use this repositories. Everything works fine so far.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/spring/application-context.xml" })
@Transactional
@Import(NeighborinoNeo4jConfiguration.class)
public class UserFactoryTest {
    private UserFactory userFactory;
    ...
}

@Named
@Stateless
public class UserFactory {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;
    ...
}
```

Now, I want to integrate this new repositories-classes into my JavaEE7-application, which I am deploying to a wildfly-8.1.

Adding the mentioned UserRepository to my application and deploying it results in following error:

```
javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unable to resolve a bean for 'org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext' with qualifiers [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()].
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.cdi.Neo4jCdiRepositoryExtension.createRepositoryBean(Neo4jCdiRepositoryExtension.java:109)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.cdi.Neo4jCdiRepositoryExtension.afterBeanDiscovery(Neo4jCdiRepositoryExtension.java:83)
...
```

To make myself clear: Just by adding this new interface to my source-code and deploying it, results in this error in the application-server. The app without this repository is deployed just fine.

As far as I can see, *Neo4jCdiRepositoryExtension.createRepositoryBean()*, runs too early. I have an own *@ApplicationScoped*-bean "Application" which, without this repository in the source-code, does the spring-configuration. But with this repository added, this ApplicationScoped-bean "Application" is not executed at all; and I assume this *UnsatisfiedResolutionException* occurs, because spring-configuration was not done before *Neo4jCdiRepositoryExtension* runs . I guess my problem could be solved by having the repositories initialization done after my "Application"-bean.

so... **How do I load spring-data-neo4j repositories lazily?**

Hint#1: *@NoRepositoryBean* makes the app deployable again. Of course, I cannot use the UserRepository.

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<User> {}
```

Hint#2: *@Lazy* does not help, same error.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
@Lazy
public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<User> {
```

versions:

```
pom.xml:
<spring.version>4.0.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring.data.neo4j.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.data.neo4j.version>
```

Comment: Looks like this issue https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-470

Comment: Hmm, nice hint, but I wonder why this bug-report remains open. Pull-requests seem to be merged.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to develop a workaround. In short I stopped using "@Autowired" at all and falled back to using javax.inject.Inject etc. again, and I am boostrapping spring-data-neo4j in good old fashioned "ClassPathXmlApplicationContext" way.

The main difficulty was to find out, **how to build a spring-data-neo4j repository** on my own. It is easy.

```
// The repo you want to have an instance of.

@NoRepositoryBean // Has to be here to avoid UnsatisfiedResolutionException from question. 
public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<User> {
}
```

(Hint: "@NoRepositoryBean" is required on your repository-interfaces. Even tough I removed "@EnableNeo4jRepositories(...)".)

I assume you have a running springApplication:

```
    final ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "spring/application-context.xml");
    final Neo4jTemplate neo4jTemplate = applicationContext .getBean(Neo4jTemplate.class);
    final Neo4jMappingContext neo4jMappingContext = applicationContext .getBean(Neo4jMappingContext.class);
```

Next is to create a GraphRepositoryFactory, which is needed to build the repositories:

```
org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepositoryFactory graphRepositoryFactory = new GraphRepositoryFactory(neo4jTemplate, neo4jMappingContext);
UserRepository userRepository = graphRepositoryFactory.getRepository(UserRepository.class);
```