# Spring Data Neo4J and CDI

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data, cdi

I setup Spring Data Neo4J following this tutorial: http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-neo4j/ and changed this slightly to use it on the Neo4J server and this runs well.

Then I tried to find an example, how I can use the repositories within a CDI environment as outlined in these examples : http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpd.misc.cdi-integration

Merely, I can not find any example what I have to provide to make this run with Neo4J.

So my question is : did anybody try to setup Neo4j with Spring Data and CDI and can provide an example, how I have to set up Spring configuration for CDI and how I can make Repositories accessable for @Inject ? Please consider that I'm pretty new in the Spring Data and Neo4J topic ;)
Thanks in advance !

Joern

Answer (score 0):

At least I found something that seems to work. I extended the Neo4JConfiguration to set up the Neo4J server connection. Within this class I produce also the needed repositories. The repositories itself have to be annotated with @NoRepositoryBean

```
public class MyNeo4JConfiguration extends Neo4jConfiguration {

GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
    return new SpringRestGraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data");
}

public GraphDatabase graphDatabase() {
    if (graphDatabaseService() instanceof GraphDatabase)
        return (GraphDatabase) graphDatabaseService();
    return new DelegatingGraphDatabase(graphDatabaseService());
}

@Produces
PersonRepository getPersonRepository() {
    GraphRepositoryFactory factory;
    try {
        factory = new GraphRepositoryFactory(new Neo4jTemplate(
                this.graphDatabase()), this.neo4jMappingContext());
        PersonRepository personRepository = factory
                .getRepository(PersonRepository.class);
        return personRepository;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The repository :

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface PersonRepository extends GraphRepository<Person> {
    Person findByName(String name);
    Iterable<Person> findByTeammatesName(String name);
}
```

The PersonRepository can now be injected with @Inject.

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26363430/how-do-i-load-spring-data-neo4j-repositories-lazily) post !!!